# query_posts creating unwanted links out of excerpt and title in loop

Tags: php, wordpress

For some reason after the first post, there are links being created out of the content retrieved from `the_excerpt` and `the_title`. Any ideas why this would be happening?

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php query_posts('category_name=uncategorized&showposts=3'); ?> <?php
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<br /> 
<?php echo the_post_thumbnail( 'latest-news'); ?>
<?php 
the_title(); ?> &nbsp; <br />
<?php
the_excerpt();
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
endif; 
?>
```

Here is the site, it is the "Latest News" section after you scroll down...
http://hailstorm_new.hailstormcommerce.com/
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=uncategorized&showposts=3'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<br /> 
   <?php echo the_post_thumbnail( 'latest-news'); ?>
   <?php the_title(); ?>
   <br />
   <?php the_excerpt();
endwhile;
endif; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

I've come across it before, can't remember the exact solution but I think your loop is ordered wrong... Try doing what I've posted above first, then post whether it fixed it or not.

Comment: I think its something to do with the characters and the "Continue Reading" link getting cut off before the `<a>` tag is closed.

Answer (score 0):

query_posts() should be at beginning of loop and wp_reset_postdata() should be at very end.
Like so:

```
<?php 
    query_posts('category_name=uncategorized&showposts=3');
    if ( have_posts() ) :
        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<br /> 
<?php 
            echo the_post_thumbnail( 'latest-news');
            the_title(); ?> &nbsp; <br />
<?php
            the_excerpt();
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, the `<a>` tag that is created by `the_excerpt` for the "Continue Reading" part was getting cut off early, meaning the first one never closed, leaving everything after it as a link.

Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Okay great... make sure you order the loop correctly like mine and ronalds posts have done as well.